# How do I call a defined function in another php script?

Tags: php, html

how do I call a defined function from a php script in another one?

I've got funktion.php which returns the time of the day.

```
<?php

  date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");

 function Uhrzeit()
 {
     echo date( 'H:i:s' );
}

 Uhrzeit();
?>
```

I'd like to call the function in another php script(test.php) so that **Uhrzeit();** from test.php has access to the function Uhrzeit() from funktion.php.

How do I implement it?

Any help or hint or link is much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
require_once("funktion.php");
Uhrzeit();
?>
```

(Edit: changed `include` to `require_once`, since it is more appropriate for this task.)

Comment: Done. Could't do it b4 because of the time out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to use the return within the include, now this is not the best idea as its a waste of a file but non the less knowledge is knowledge:

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    return date( 'H:i:s' );
?>
```

and use like

```
echo include 'functions.php';
```

Comment: Knowledege is knowledge and I'm thankful for every piece of it. Ty